# Why Firefox is injecting "use strict"; in class methods?

Tags: javascript, firefox, strict

I have the following code:

```js
class A {
 contructor(){
  }
  toString(){
   return [this.b.toString(),this.toString.toString()].join('\n');
  }
  b(){
  }
}
console.log(new A().toString());

function a (){}
a.prototype.b = function(){
  
}
a.prototype.toString = function toString(){
  return [a.prototype.b.toString(), a.prototype.toString.toString()].join('\n');
}
console.log(new a().toString());
```

The output in Firefox is:

```
function b(){
"use strict";

  }
function toString(){
"use strict";

    return [this.b.toString(),this.toString.toString()].join('\n');
  }
function (){

}
function toString(){
  return [a.prototype.b.toString(), a.prototype.toString.toString()].join('\n');
}
```

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) we can see the uses of "use strict":

> Strict mode makes several changes to normal JavaScript semantics.
>   First, strict mode eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by
>   changing them to throw errors. Second, strict mode fixes mistakes that
>   make it difficult for JavaScript engines to perform optimizations:
>   strict mode code can sometimes be made to run faster than identical
>   code that's not strict mode. Third, strict mode prohibits some syntax
>   likely to be defined in future versions of ECMAScript.

But no one seems to be the reason. Is there a reason for Firefox to inject it in the functions? Is something that it does programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Strict mode
>
> The bodies of class declarations and class expressions are executed in strict mode.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Strict_mode

Pretty self-explanatory. Not much to discuss.